# cannot access the vector members of a class

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have tried to access the members of a class `Part` that are vector elements of type integer inside the vector `tasks`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Part{
    vector<int> tasks;
    public:

    void setTasks(void);
    void getTasks(void);
};
void Part::setTasks(void){
    vector<int>::iterator it;
    int i=1;
    for (it = this->tasks.begin(); it != this->tasks.end(); ++it)
    {
        *it=i;
        i=i+1;
    }
}

void Part::getTasks(void){
    vector<int>::iterator it;
    for (it = this->tasks.begin(); it != this->tasks.end(); ++it)
       cout<<*it<<"\t";
}
int main()
{
    Part one;
    one.setTasks();
    one.getTasks();

    return 0;
}
```

I am simply trying to access the values and print them yet failing. There is no compilation error. In run-time, nothing is outputted in the terminal. Where is the error?

Comment: `tasks` is empty. You never put anything in it. So, both `setTasks` and `getTasks` do nothing. What output were you expecting? (How many items?)

Comment: Your vector is empty. Try giving it a size. For example, `vector<int> tasks(10)`. See [option 3 in this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

Comment: If you want something like an array, but more C++y, you should have a look at `std::array`. (BTW, `(void)` is a C thing, it's not necessary, or recommended, in C++.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A default constructed `vector` has zero size, so the `for` loop in `setTasks` is never entered (since the `begin()` and `end()` iterators are the same at that point). If you set an initial size to the `vector` your code will work as intended. For instance, try adding the following at the beginning of `setTasks`

```
tasks.resize(10); // sets vector size to 10 elements, each initialized to 0
```

Another way to write that function would be

```
#include <numeric>

...

void Part::setTasks(void){
    tasks.resize(10);
    std::iota(tasks.begin(), tasks.end(), 1); // requires C++11
}
```

---

You could also set the initial size of the `vector` in the default constructor of `Part` if you wanted to. In that case add the following public constructor

```
Part() : tasks(10)
{}
```

Yet another way to achieve setting the size upon construction would be

```
class Part{
    vector<int> tasks = vector<int>(10); // requires C++11
```

Comment: Why not just use the default constructor?

Comment: @0x499602D2 You mean set the initial size within the constructor? Of course you could, I assumed the OP wants the `vector` size to be set only when `setTasks` is called.

Comment: @Praetorian And in case, one is not sure how much space he wants to allocate to evade risk of undersizing or oversizing, `push_back` is ideal, right? I ask this for confirmation bcuz it was not mentioned.

Comment: @Praetorian Also i can also do this: `vector<int> tasks(10)` as pointed out by Daniel Le.

Comment: @userzizzy `push_back` will reallocate storage as necessary when you add new elements to the `vector`. And if you have an idea of how much storage you're going to need, then calling `reserve` followed by `push_back` can help avoid repeated allocations.

Comment: @userzizzy I'm not sure where you'd put that line. It's invalid syntax for in-class initialization, and if you place it in either `get/setTasks` you'd create a local `tasks` object that shadows the data member and any modifications you make will be lost when the function exits

Comment: @Praetorian, you can put the arguments to the vector constructor in the member initialization list, like `Foo(): v(size){...}`

Comment: @vsoftco You mean exactly like I've shown in the answer (`Part() : tasks(10)`) ;) Notice that the thing OP suggested has `vector<int>` in it, hence my confusion about where he was suggesting he could use that.

Answer (score 1):

The size of your vector is 0 when you call `setTasks()`. Your iterator doesn't get you into the for loop at all. You need to think about what exactly you want your `setTasks()` to do. How many elements of the vector did you *intend* to set? You should either define your vector with that size, or use that many number of `push_back`s instead to set your vector to the desired value.

Answer (score 0):

Your vector is empty. Try giving it a size. For example, `vector<int> tasks(10)`. See [option 3 in this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use a "back-insert" iterator (`#include <iterator>`), which internally calls `std::vector::push_back`, like this:

```
void Part::setTasks(void){
    auto back_it = std::back_inserter(tasks);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        *back_it++ = i;
}
```

This kind of iterator is especially useful in algorithms where your destination size is unknown. Although if you know the size in advance, you should use `reserve/resize` or specify the size at construction, since push-ing back into a vector can sometimes be slow due to re-allocation.